# How do we know when a Perl core module is deprecated?

Tags: perl, module, deprecated

Given a particular module that used to be supported as part of Perl core, how do I tell if it's supported by the Perl version I want to upgrade to?

Comment: maybe clarify the question or the answer - some modules are booted out of the core but not deprecated per se

Comment: I usually read perldelta documentation in each perl version released

Comment: You can provide what you think the answer is. :)

Comment: to put it another way, the title asks one question and the body another; your answer addresses both, but doesn't make the distinction clear

Comment: You know how to edit things. :)

Answer (score 5):

[perlpolicy](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpolicy.html#BACKWARD-COMPATIBILITY-AND-DEPRECATION) says

> As of Perl 5.12, deprecated features and modules warn the user as they're used.

There's the [deprecate](https://metacpan.org/module/deprecate) module which provides this warning. A module is deprecated for at least one cycle before it's actually removed. That doesn't help much if you skip over several perl versions.

[Module::CoreList](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Module::CoreList) tracks deprecated modules too.

The fallback is reading the *perldelta* pages to find the changes between the version they are using and the version they want to upgrade too.